# Spring Security Along with cors gives 302 and returns login page

Tags: java, angular, spring-mvc, spring-security, cors

Its been few weeks since I started working with spring, Now I am trying to expand my knowledge. What I am trying to do is.

I have a Spring MVC application that uses spring security and has simple login form and after login some simple CRUD operations, it works well when I login application using jsp form.

but when I do the similar action from an ANGULAR application the request doesn't land and returns status code 302 then another request is made to the login page of the spring application and the html of login is returned.

below are the Configuration classes I am using:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired(required = true)
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    private static final String[] AUTH_WHITELIST = {

            // -- swagger ui
            "/swagger-resources/**", "/swagger-ui.html", "/v2/api-docs",
            "/webjars/**", "/swagger.json", "/swagger*/**", "/user/**" };

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    };

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(
                passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**");
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/v2/api-docs/**");
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/swagger.json");
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/swagger-ui.html");
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/swagger-resources/**");
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/webjars/**");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers(AUTH_WHITELIST)
                .authenticated().anyRequest().permitAll().and()
                .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "USER")
                .and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login**").permitAll()
                .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/loginAction").permitAll().and().logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login").permitAll()
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID").invalidateHttpSession(true).and()
                .csrf().disable();

        http.sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)
                .maximumSessions(1).expiredUrl("/login.jsp");

    }

    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        final CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:4200"));
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("HEAD", "GET", "POST",
                "PUT", "DELETE", "PATCH"));

        configuration.setAllowCredentials(false);

        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Authorization",
                "Cache-Control", "Content-Type","X-Requested-With","Access-Control-Allow-Headers","Accept"));

        configuration.addAllowedHeader("*");
        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }



}
```

Another config class named WebConfig which implements WebMvcConfigurer

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:documentation.properties")
@ComponentScans(value = {
        @ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.xx.xx.xx" }),
        @ComponentScan("com.xx.xx.xx") })
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
        registry.jsp().prefix("/WEB-INF/views/").suffix(".jsp");
    }

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {

        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
                .allowedMethods("PUT", "DELETE")
                .allowedHeaders("Authorization", "Cache-Control",
                        "Content-Type", "X-Requested-With",
                        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers")
                .exposedHeaders("Cache-Control", "Content-Type")
                .allowCredentials(false).maxAge(4800);

        // Add more mappings...
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

        // Register resource handler for resources
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/resources/")
                .setCacheControl(
                        CacheControl.maxAge(2, TimeUnit.HOURS).cachePublic());

        registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html").addResourceLocations(
                "classpath:/META-INF/resources/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**").addResourceLocations(
                "classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    }

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
    }
}
```

And the restful API, I am trying to call from ANGULAR Application.

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200", maxAge = 4800, allowCredentials = "false")
@RestController
public class UserController {
    private static final Class<UserController> className = UserController.class;
    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @CrossOrigin
    @PostMapping(value = "/user/authenticate")
    @ApiOperation(value = "Authenticate User", notes = "${UserController.authenticate.notes}")
    public void authenticate(
            @ApiParam(value = "${UserController.authenticate.body}", required = true) @RequestBody String userData,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("called");
        try {
            String result = userService.authenticateUser(userData);
            response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
            response.getWriter().write(result);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

I am calling authenticate api with POST body. url is 
"http://localhost:8080/spring-security-example/user/authenticate".
Now I will share screen shots of the network traffic when I try to login from angular application.

1. Screen 1: The Original First request but with request method ORIGIN
2. Screen 2: The second reqeust that was sent automatically with
   request method GET should be POST i dont know where it gets changed
3. Screen 3: first request to the login jsp which also was not sent by
   me
4. Screen 4: last request in which u can see code of login.jsp
   returned

[image: The Original First request but with request method ORIGIN]

[image: The second reqeust that was sent automatically with request method GET should be POST i dont know where it gets changed]

[image: first request to the login jsp which also was not sent by me]

[image: last request in which u can see code of login.jsp returned]

Now If I remove `csrf().disable()` from HttpSecurity, i will have only two requests on the authenticate first will be with Request-method ORIGIN and the next will be Request-method POST but it will return 403 forbidden as spring block csrf requests when csrf is enabled.

So My question is what I am doing wrong here, and why the request method gets changed to GET by itself with `csrf().disable()`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After changing my HttpConfigure Security I got it working, below is the new code for it.

```
http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/swagger-resources/**", "/swagger-ui.html", "/v2/api-docs",
            "/webjars/**", "/swagger.json", "/swagger*/**", "/user/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/**").authenticated().and().authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "USER").and().headers().and()
                .exceptionHandling().and().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login**").permitAll().and().formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login").loginProcessingUrl("/loginAction")
                .permitAll().and().logout().logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login").permitAll()
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID").invalidateHttpSession(true).and()
                .exceptionHandling().and().cors().and().csrf().disable();
```

It seems to me that it was only configuration issue. Now i donot get status 302 in response.

Comment: what was changed?